How to make an extension In Google Chrome (windows) Enabled But User Cannot Use It
How to make an extension In Google Chrome (windows)  Enabled But User Cannot Use It.
My friend is addicted to bad habits, and I want to make his internet experience safer to help him quit these habits.
I downloaded a parental app (Qustodio) to control what he uses on the internet, so I blocked bad sites, social media, etc.
Recently, he wants to use Telegram for his studies, but I want to block the Telegram search feature. I searched for a way to remove the web.telegram search bar and used the Stylish extension for this purpose. I managed to force it to install using the registry.
However, I want the extension to be enabled but want to prevent the user from being able to open it or modify it. In other words, I want the extension to be active without the user being able to access it.
How can I achieve this?
Thank you!

or if i can make password for chrome extensions this will be amazing

Unless the extension itself supports it, you can't. Find one that supports password protection or sometihng

Part of the basic function of a plugin in a browser is that the user of the browser can control it. You will need to find a solution that exists outside the browser, and even for that you'll need to make sure your friend does not have administrator permissions on the computer to prevent him circumventing or removing those controls. Yours is a laudable goal, but a browser plugin is more voluntary than you need.
